# QGIS plugin for georeferencing/aligning images

Tags: qgis

Is there a plugin in QGIS that allows you to rotate, stretch, align etc. an aerial image, similar to how one can use image overlay in Google Earth?

Comment: you can do it with native QGIS functionality, no plugins needed for this. See QGIS documentation https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/georeferencer.html

Comment: For behaviour like the google earth overlay, take a look at https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/FreehandRasterGeoreferencer/